# set different language in android studio

Tags: android, json, yahoo-weather-api

am new in android studio and I am trying to make my simple app weather info via yahoo weather service JSON data , i would like to make a different language display in my app , example English and Arabic am working on string.xml and i translate some words in main activity , am try translate condition Text to Arabic but not working , if there way on string ?  i want translate on condition Text , i hope get answer withe code .

my code if any one can help my

```
package net.digitalphantom.app.weatherapp;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import net.digitalphantom.app.weatherapp.data.Channel;
import net.digitalphantom.app.weatherapp.data.Condition;
import net.digitalphantom.app.weatherapp.data.LocationResult;
import net.digitalphantom.app.weatherapp.data.Units;
import net.digitalphantom.app.weatherapp.fragments.WeatherConditionFragment;
import net.digitalphantom.app.weatherapp.listener.GeocodingServiceListener;
import net.digitalphantom.app.weatherapp.listener.WeatherServiceListener;
import net.digitalphantom.app.weatherapp.service.WeatherCacheService;
import net.digitalphantom.app.weatherapp.service.GoogleMapsGeocodingService;
import net.digitalphantom.app.weatherapp.service.YahooWeatherService;

public class WeatherActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements WeatherServiceListener, GeocodingServiceListener, LocationListener {

    public static int GET_WEATHER_FROM_CURRENT_LOCATION = 1979455;

    private ImageView weatherIconImageView;
    private TextView temperatureTextView;
    private TextView conditionTextView;
    private TextView locationTextView;

    private YahooWeatherService weatherService;
    private GoogleMapsGeocodingService geocodingService;
    private WeatherCacheService cacheService;

    private ProgressDialog loadingDialog;

    // weather service fail flag
    private boolean weatherServicesHasFailed = false;

    private SharedPreferences preferences = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_weather);

        weatherIconImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.weatherIconImageView);
        temperatureTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.temperatureTextView);
        conditionTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.conditionTextView);
        locationTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.locationTextView);

        preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

        weatherService = new YahooWeatherService(this);
        weatherService.setTemperatureUnit(preferences.getString(getString(R.string.pref_temperature_unit), null));

        geocodingService = new GoogleMapsGeocodingService(this);
        cacheService = new WeatherCacheService(this);

        if (preferences.getBoolean(getString(R.string.pref_needs_setup), true)) {
            startSettingsActivity();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        loadingDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        loadingDialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.loading));
        loadingDialog.setCancelable(false);
        loadingDialog.show();

        String location = null;

        if (preferences.getBoolean(getString(R.string.pref_geolocation_enabled), true)) {
            String locationCache = preferences.getString(getString(R.string.pref_cached_location), null);

            if (locationCache == null) {
                getWeatherFromCurrentLocation();
            } else {
                location = locationCache;
            }
        } else {
            location = preferences.getString(getString(R.string.pref_manual_location), null);
        }

        if (location != null) {
            weatherService.refreshWeather(location);
        }
    }

    private void getWeatherFromCurrentLocation() {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
            }, GET_WEATHER_FROM_CURRENT_LOCATION);

            return;
        }

        // system's LocationManager
        final LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        boolean isNetworkEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        boolean isGPSEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        Criteria locationCriteria = new Criteria();

        if (isNetworkEnabled) {
            locationCriteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_COARSE);
        } else if (isGPSEnabled) {
            locationCriteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
        }

        locationManager.requestSingleUpdate(locationCriteria, this, null);
    }

    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        if (requestCode == WeatherActivity.GET_WEATHER_FROM_CURRENT_LOCATION) {
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                getWeatherFromCurrentLocation();
            } else {
                loadingDialog.hide();

                AlertDialog messageDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                        .setMessage(getString(R.string.location_permission_needed))
                        .setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.disable_geolocation), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                startSettingsActivity();
                            }
                        })
                        .create();

                messageDialog.show();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    private void startSettingsActivity() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.currentLocation:
                loadingDialog.show();
                getWeatherFromCurrentLocation();
                return true;
            case R.id.settings:
                startSettingsActivity();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void serviceSuccess(Channel channel) {
        loadingDialog.hide();

        Condition condition = channel.getItem().getCondition();
        Units units = channel.getUnits();
        Condition[] forecast = channel.getItem().getForecast();

        int weatherIconImageResource = getResources().getIdentifier("icon_" + condition.getCode(), "drawable", getPackageName());

        weatherIconImageView.setImageResource(weatherIconImageResource);
        temperatureTextView.setText(getString(R.string.temperature_output, condition.getTemperature(), units.getTemperature()));
        conditionTextView.setText(condition.getDescription());
        locationTextView.setText(channel.getLocation());

        for (int day = 0; day < forecast.length; day++) {
            if (day >= 5) {
                break;
            }

            Condition currentCondition = forecast[day];

            int viewId = getResources().getIdentifier("forecast_" + day, "id", getPackageName());
            WeatherConditionFragment fragment = (WeatherConditionFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(viewId);

            if (fragment != null) {
                fragment.loadForecast(currentCondition, channel.getUnits());
            }
        }

        cacheService.save(channel);
    }

    @Override
    public void serviceFailure(Exception exception) {
        // display error if this is the second failure
        if (weatherServicesHasFailed) {
            loadingDialog.hide();
            Toast.makeText(this, exception.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            // error doing reverse geocoding, load weather data from cache
            weatherServicesHasFailed = true;
            // OPTIONAL: let the user know an error has occurred then fallback to the cached data
            Toast.makeText(this, exception.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            cacheService.load(this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void geocodeSuccess(LocationResult location) {
        // completed geocoding successfully
        weatherService.refreshWeather(location.getAddress());

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.putString(getString(R.string.pref_cached_location), location.getAddress());
        editor.apply();
    }

    @Override
    public void geocodeFailure(Exception exception) {
        // GeoCoding failed, try loading weather data from the cache
        cacheService.load(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        geocodingService.refreshLocation(location);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {
        // OPTIONAL: implement your custom logic here
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {
        // OPTIONAL: implement your custom logic here
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {
        // OPTIONAL: implement your custom logic here
    }
}
```

thank you

Comment: If your code produces an error post the full logcat output of that error, point out which line of code caused it, and ask a specific question about it.

Comment: sorry i well update my question , i mean error not display in app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/***You need to create separate String file for both arabic and English***/

English
 Values
  String.xml
Arabic   
 Values-ar
  String.xml

/**You can change the application language using the following code:**/

 language =  "en"; or  language =  "ar";

@Override
public void recreate()
{
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 14)
    {
        super.recreate();
    }
    else
    {
        startActivity(getIntent());
        finish();
    }
}

private void updateLanguage(String language)
{
    Locale locale = new Locale(language);
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    config.locale = locale;
    getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

    SharedPreferences languagepref = getSharedPreferences("language",MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = languagepref.edit();
    editor.putString("languageToLoad",language);
    editor.apply();

    recreate();
}
```

Comment: Please format your answers correctly before posting them.

Comment: thank you for answer , can i make string.xml just for condition Text ? , example , cloud : صحوه

Comment: Yes,as i earlier said create separate String file for both arabic and English

Create values-en for english and set string as:
<string name="cloud">cloud</string>

Create another folder values-ar for Arabic and set string as:
<string name="cloud">صحوه</string>

Comment: okay , good the point is how i set the Resources ? exmple if i make string_ar.xml and inside string_ar.xml `<string name="cloud">صحوه</string>` , how i set him in main activity ? like this ?  `conditionTextView.setText(condition.getDescription().getResources());` ?

Comment: You can set in your main activity like this:
conditionTextView.setText(MainAcivity.this.getResources().getText(R.string. cloud));

Comment: See you need to same String for different languages buddy as i said earlier
string_ar.xml --> <string name="cloud">صحوه</string>  and for 
English string_en.xml --><string name="cloud">cloud</string>

Answer (score 1):

To translate an app you must go to the `Translations Editor` which is accessible when you open `strings.xml`. You will have to translate every string yourself and put the desired translation into the `Translations Editor`. To access different translations the user will have to have their `Locale` on their device set to one of the country codes that you provide support for. For example in your app you would end up having `strings.xml` and `strings.xml (us)` and the app would use `Strings` from `strings.xml` as default unless their locale was set to `us` in which case they would use the `strings.xml (us)` strings

Comment: thank you for answer , can i make string.xml just for condition Text ?

Comment: If you're asking if you can use a ternary like `setText(isArabic ? cloud : صحوه");` I suppose you could, but it would become quite tedious to do so for every place you set a string

Comment: okay , good the point is how i set the Resources ? exmple if i make string_ar.xml and inside string_ar.xml <string name="cloud">صحوه</string> , how i set him in main activity ? like this ? conditionTextView.setText(condition.getDescription().getReso‌​urces()); ?

Comment: If you set up the translations editor and properly set the `Locale` on your device by going into the settings you just have to use `getString()` regularly :)

That's the beauty of Translations Editor, you don't have to deal with any translating inside your java files

Comment: you mean `conditionTextView.setText(condition.getDescription().getReso‌​‌​urces()); `